# heroku not serving css

Tags: python, css, django, heroku

I have the following code in my `settings.py` in django.

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'hhhh.utils.MediaRootS3BotoStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'hhhh.utils.StaticRootS3BotoStorage'
S3DIRECT_REGION = 'us-west-2'
S3_URL = '//%s.s3.amazonaws.com/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
MEDIA_URL = '//%s.s3.amazonaws.com/media/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_URL
STATIC_URL = S3_URL + 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = STATIC_URL + 'static_root/'
```

Heroku is not serving the ststic files. any ideas. I have the allowed hosts set to my site and heroku.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your variables correctly, your static URL is built as so: 
S3_URL + static + static_root

So, if your s3 bucket is named hhhh, then the final URL is
//hhhh.s3.amazonaws.com/static/static_root

Do files exist in that location?

For more info, Heroku offers a sample settings.py file regarding Django static files here: serving static assets with Django: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets

This page speaks specifically to hosting s3 files on s3 with heroku:
http://www.jorgechang.com/blog/howto-deploy-a-fault-tolerant-django-app-on-aws-part-2-moving-static-media-files-to-s3/

The author's STATIC_ROOT variable is blank, because static locations of files are set- and then the code later refers to the files on an Amazons3 location- it seems his code collects static files from a specific place and puts them in S3, then references them from there. You seem to be attempting to refer directly to an amazon s3 URL on your static_root var, so this laws gives you an alternate way to go it.